# Many a hrefs from JSON, on toggle click make diffrent id appear

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON file with movies in theaters. I want to make info appear for right movie when I click on movie title which are many. My code is not working, but I am able to make all the movies appear on click, no matter what movie.

I want to be able to click, let's say, "Ender's Game", and then make info div appear with only info about that film. My code is here below:

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON('json/store.json', function(results) {
       //Get movie title
        for (var i = 0; i < results['results'].length; i++) {
            var title = '<p><a href="#">' + results['results'][i].title + '</a></p>';
            $('#movies').append(title);
         }





        for (var i = 0; i < results['results'].length; i++) {
            var title = $('#info').append("<p class='biohus'>" + results['results'][i].title + "</p>");
            var img = $('#info').append("<img id='myndbio' width='200' height='300' class='img' src =" + results['results'][i].image + ">");
            }




$('.title').click(function(){ 
    $(this).parent().find('#info').slideToggle("slow");
});


$('.title').click(function(){ 
    var dataMovieId = $(this).attr('data-movie-id');
    $('#'+dataMovieId).slideToggle("slow");
});

});
});
```

Html:

```
<div id="bio" class = "content">
        <center><h1 class="cinemaheadline">Myndir í bíó</h1></center>
        <?php include 'php/curl.php';?>

        <div id="movies" class="movies">
            <!-- Movies -->
        </div>

        <div id="info" class="info">
            <!-- info -->
        </div>
    </div>
```

and php for connection to api:

```
   <?php
//check if you have curl loaded
if(!function_exists("curl_init")) die("cURL extension is not installed");
//url
$url = 'http://apis.is/cinema';
$storejson = 'json/store.json';
//skrifa
$fw = fopen($storejson, 'w'); 
//start curl
$ch=curl_init($url);
//set options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
//execute
$r=curl_exec($ch);
//close curl
curl_close($ch);

$arr = json_decode($r,true);
fwrite($fw, json_encode($arr, TRUE));
?>
```

Comment: There is absolutely no reason you need to make the same AJAX call twice to get the same data. You also need to understand that your `click()` call will likely execute before the AJAX requests are completed (because they are asynchronous), thus not binding your click handler to any actual elements. Nor does it have access to the results of the AJAX calls.

Comment: Simple problem, but without a little HTML it will be hard for us to give you the right code.

Comment: <div id="bio" class = "content">
        <center><h1>Movies in Theater</h1></center>
        <?php include 'php/curl.php';?>
        <div id="movies" class="movies"></div>
        <div id="info" class="info"></div>
    </div>

Comment: Here is the code from above

Comment: @jonjonson please edit your original post with the html for better reading and for other SOers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem you have here is that you need some way of linking the title with the info. Either have the title and info wrapped in its own div for each movie, or use some attribute (data-movie) and give it a name or number which can associate the title and the info.

If the first way you'll need to do something like

```
$('.title').click(function(){ 
    $(this).parent().find('.info').slideToggle("slow");
});
```

and the second way would be something like;

```
$('.title').click(function(){ 
    var dataMovieId = $(this).attr('data-movie-id');
    $('#'+dataMovieId).slideToggle("slow");
});
```

Lastly you should not be using ids the way you are. eg you will be outputting img tags with the same ids. You should only use an id once on a page.

EDIT: Full code;

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON('json/store.json', function(results) {
        for (var i = 0; i < results['results'].length; i++) {
            // title link. note the data-id attr which is i, which we will put into the movie info, to tie them together
            var title = '<p><a href="#" data-id="'+i+'">' + results['results'][i].title + '</a></p>';

            // info section
            var infoTitle = "<p class='biohus'>" + results['results'][i].title + "</p>";
            var infoImg = "<img id='myndbio' width='200' height='300' class='img' src =" + results['results'][i].image + ">";
            // wrap title and image in a div with the data-id attr and i
            var info = '<div class="movie-info data-id="'+i+'">'+infoTitle+infoImg+'</div>';

            // place both title and info sections in the right spots
            $('#movies').append(title);
            $('#info').append(info);
         }
    });

    // set up click handlers
    $('#movies a').click(function(){
        // find data id of clicked movie
        var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
        // find movie info with correct id and show
        $('#info .movie-info[data-id="'+id+'"]').slideToggle("slow");
    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help I will let you know if this works. But I am getting the json content from a webpage and the json file is constantly being updated. Would this what you said work to?

Comment: Yep either way would work. But as Mike Brant suggested, and even moreso now since the json file is going to be changing a lot, you only want to do one request to get the json, then do what you want with it. 

But the code you put above it seems you might need to do the second way.

Comment: I'm a beginner so do you mind if I ask you another question. It's about the data id or (data-movie-id) and $('#'+dataMovieId). I dont get it if you have time could you explain for dummy and maybe give me an exsample? :/

Comment: Thank you so much for your help I will get on it and see if it works :)

Comment: No worries at all. If you have any issues don't hesitate to come back! :)

Comment: hey again it won't work for me the code you have written. The a hrefs for titles appear but the info won't. Do you think you know why. Here is a link to my page under the navbar link Í BÍÓ                         https://notendur.hi.is/~sth132/Lokaverkefnireal/index_Lokaverkefni.php#

Comment: Thanks Nick yebb I have mangae to sort this out :) thanks again